# Cascading list on Android

Tags: android, android-listview, horizontalscrollview, android-tablelayout

I have to rework my UI, something like the pattern "cascading list".

I've not found examples on Android, i'm thinking of doing it with a HorizontalScrollView that fill the screen, and then a TableLayout in which i'll put some ListViews.

When the user clicks on an item of the listView, it displays another list on its right.
The "back" button destroys/hides the list. When there are several lists on the screen, the user can scroll thanks to the HorizontalScrollView.

What do you think of that ?

Thx